# The cost function derivation in andrew ng machine learning course

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Can you please give me how did Andrew NG, came up with the formula for cost function

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=0}^m{(H_\theta(x^i)-y^i))^2}$$

AFAIK the square is being taken to handle the negative values since
$y^2 = H_\theta(x)^2$ is same as $y = H_\theta(X)$

By removing from square from both sides. Is my understanding right? but why is sum being taken for all the samples in the training set

I have gone through the link [Help understanding machine learning cost function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957125/help-understanding-machine-learning-cost-function)

But still unable to understand the need to take sum of the squares and again dividing by 2m.

Kindly help me

Comment: If it is his course, why don't you ask him or check the course site for resources?

Comment: The idea is to minimize the distance from the line over each of the points in the dataset. By adding up the distance from each point, we get an idea for how our estimate does over the whole training set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me see if the following helps. First, remember:

- $H_\theta$ is the model that we are trying to learn (from your tag, a linear function; e.g. in 1D, $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and $H_\theta(x) = \theta_1 + \theta_2x$). In order to "learn" (or even define) the function $H_\theta$, we need to find $\theta$.
- Call $D=\{(x^i,y^i)\;\forall\;i\in[1,m]\}$ our training dataset. What it means is that, for each $x^i$, we want our learned function to produce something close to $y^i$. In other words, we want $H_\theta(x^i)$ to be close to $y^i$.

So our goal is to produce such a function $H_\theta$ using $D$.
One way to do this is to define our goal as an optimization problem. So we define a *cost function*, denoted $J(\theta)$, that measures how bad our current $H_\theta$ is, which we will then try to minimize.

In essence, if $J(\theta)$ is very small (i.e. the cost is low), then we can say that $ H_\theta $ is doing a good job on $D$. This suggests we should sum over $D$. In essence, for every point $(x,y)$ in the dataset, we will measure the error that $H_\theta$ makes on that point, i.e. how far $H_\theta(x)$ is from $y$. So then the total error, or cost, will be the *sum* of the errors on these individual points.

Let's try something simple: $$ J_{\text{bad}}(\theta) = \sum_i H_\theta(x^i) - y^i $$
so if $H_\theta(x^i) = y^i$ all the time, we get $J_1=0$. That's good, but there's a problem. If $H_\theta$ is negative, then the cost is shrinking. So, if we optimize this, we will just want to make $H_\theta$ very negative! That's just dumb, so we need to fix this. One simple way is to take the square:
$$ J_{\text{better}}(\theta) = \sum_i (H_\theta(x^i) - y^i)^2 $$
This is much better. The smallest that $J_{\text{better}}$ can ever be is zero, and this can *only* happen if $H_\theta$ scores *perfectly* on every data point. Since it is always positive, it reminds one of an energy, which is nice.

Now to finish off the cost function. First, we divide by $m$, so that instead of being the *total* error (or cost) of the function, it is the *average* error instead. Then, we also divide by $2$, because there is a square in the cost function. So, when we take the derivative (which we will, in order to optimize it), the square will generate a $2$ and cancel out. *It's just aesthetics really*.

So anyway, the final function is: $$ J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_i (H_\theta(x^i) - y^i)^2 $$

Recap: (1) We want to make *every* $H_\theta(x^i) \approx y^i$, so we define a distance between them (their *squared* difference, because we want to minimize to zero and want the "energy" or "cost" to always be positive) called the error, and sum over the whole dataset to get the total error. (2) We divide by $2m$ because it is more aesthetically pleasing to consider the average error and we want to cancel the inevitable $2$ from differentiation.

Sorry if this was too basic; hopefully it helped!

---

Edit: note that when we are considering the error, we can use *any* distance metric. For instance, we could instead use the distance: $$ J_p(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_i |H_\theta(x^i) - y^i|^p $$
Note that there will be a difference: the higher $p$ is, the more impact outliers will have on the function. The case $p=2$ is a natural one in ML because it is (the square of) the classical Euclidean distance.
The case $p=1$ is certainly reasonable as well (though it comes with the drawback of being non-differentiable at $0$).

However, for linear regression specifically, there is extra reason to use the squared distance, also called the [ordinary least squares (OLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) problem (note: this is mathematically slightly more advanced). If we assume that our dataset $D$ has been generated from a linear model with Gaussian noise $Y=\alpha X + \mathcal{E}$, then the minimizer of OLS is the [maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) of the model parameters. See also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12562/equivalence-between-least-squares-and-mle-in-gaussian-model). So there is a beautiful connection between statistics, linear algebra, and optimization in this case.

See also [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46019/why-squared-residuals-instead-of-absolute-residuals-in-ols-estimation), which talks a little more about other reasons to choose the sum of squares rather than the sum of absolute values.

Comment: Awesome explanation really loved it. But two questions sorry if I sound really dumb just trying to understand. 1. We are taking the squares of the differences in order to avoid negative values. why can we use modulus to avoid negative values?  2. I get the intuition that we are taking checking for every x value the difference between h(x) and y to be minimum i.e. close to zero. But what is a need to take sum of the squared differences?

Comment: @Siddarth I've added another section; is that helpful?

Comment: Thanks a lot again for explanation, now it makes perfect sense that we are trying to calculate the distance between the actual output and our hypothetical output. but sorry again for another question if we are calculating for p=2, then there should be a square root existing right for the distance calculation?. or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: @Siddarth Yes, if we are talking about the classical [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) or [$L_p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), then a root is needed (i.e. $(\cdot)^{1/p}$), but here we only needed a [*general distance metric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). What I put in the answer is just an example. We do not need to use the classical standard distances, just any metric. Also note that $h_\theta(x)$ and $y^i$ can be vectors (or even higher dimensional arrays), so then one can use some of these other distances.

Comment: Thanks again for clarification. Please suggest me some good books which I can go through to solidify my Math understanding

Comment: @siddarth It depends on what you want to know more about. One good ML book that's not too heavy on math, but has a more statistical perspective is Hastie et al, *The Elements of Statistical Learning*. I think knowing a little bit of linear algebra is also useful, if you can pick it up.